# What are "parameters" in a formula of first-order logic?

Tags: logic, notation, terminology, model-theory

I've seen the term "parameter" being used in logic literature. For example, $p_1,\dots ,p_n$ are parameters in a formula $\varphi(x,p_1,\dots,p_n)$ (this is notation for parameters). I suspect that "parameters" are just free variables, taking into account that we denote that a variable $x$ is free in a formula $\varphi$ by writing $\varphi(x)$. But I'm not sure about that and I found no definite answer on the internet thus far. So, please, tell me the precise meaning of the term "parameter" in logic.

Comment: The religious language you include at the end of most of your posts is inappropriate here - which is why users keep editing it out of your posts. You also do not need to write "thank you in advance". Please do not revert these edits.

Comment: I explain my position on religious language in posts in more detail here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/32495/7062

Answer (score 3):

Parameters are more than just free variables; in short, it's a way of incorporating elements of (a subset of) an $\mathscr L$-structure in the study of the $\mathscr L$-structure itself. To illustrate this point, let $\mathscr L = \{+, \cdot, -, 0, 1\}$ be the language of rings and consider $\mathbb R$ as an $\mathscr L$-structure. One way of talking about the element $\sqrt \pi$ in $(\mathbb R; +, \cdot, -; 0,1)$ is to define it as the only element in $\mathbb R$ which satisfies the formula (with parameter $\pi$) $$\phi(x, \pi) := (x^2 = \pi) \wedge \exists u (u^2 =x).$$
Note that as written above, $\phi(x, \pi)$ is not an $\mathscr L$-formula as $\pi$ does not belong to our language; adding $\pi$ as a parameter enables us to define in a first order way the element $\sqrt \pi$ in $\mathbb R$.

The way we do this formally is by "adding a constant to our language". Taking our example above, we consider a new language $\mathscr L' = \mathscr L \cup \{\hat{\pi}\}$ where $\hat{\pi}$ is a new constant symbol, and we expand our $\mathscr L$-structure $(\mathbb R; +, \cdot, -; 0,1)$ to an $\mathscr L'$-structure $\mathscr R$ with universe $\mathbb R$ and which interprets all function symbols and constant symbols which belong to $\mathscr L$ just as $(\mathbb R; +, \cdot, -; 0,1)$, and furthermore it interprets the new constant symbol $\hat{\pi}$ as the element $\pi \in \mathbb R$; the result is that by "naming" such element syntactically (i.e. via a new constant symbol) we can include $\pi$ in the analysis of our original $\mathscr L$-structure.

In general, instead of adding a single constant symbol one adds a new set of constant symbols, each naming an element of a "parameter set" $A \subseteq M$ from an $\mathscr L$-structure $\mathscr M$.

Comment: One important special case that's worth mentioning is the case of axiom schemata with parameters, e.g. in the induction schema of Peano Arithmetic or the specification schema of ZFC set theory. In that case, "allowing parameters" *does* correspond to taking a universal closure with respect to the free variables in the induction/separation formula.

Comment: @Z.A.K. Whoops, I missed mentioning this. Thanks for pointing it out!