# Is my understanding of parameters in First-Order language of set theory correct?

Tags: logic, set-theory, intuition

Suppose we have a formula $\varphi(x,p_1,\dots,p_n)$. We want to say that all the elements which satisfy this formula are members of a certain set $S$. If we had only a formula with a single free variable $x$, we couldn't really say much about what this $x$ is like. But if we have additional *parameters* like $p_1,\dots,p_n$, we can say a lot about the "relations" between them and $x$, and we describe them using logical connectives and predicates proper to the language of First-Order set theory. So, the statement that an object $x$ is an element of $S$ given $x$'s relations to objects $p_1,\dots,p_n$ would be such ($\square$ here stands for either $\forall$ or $\exists$).

$$
\square S \square x\square p_1\dots\square p_n \, (x \in S \leftrightarrow \varphi(x,p_1,\dots,p_n))
$$

So, my understanding is that parameters are just free variables which help the formula express all the properties we want $x$ to have. The only thing that worries me is the order of the quantifiers $\forall$ and $\exists$, as I know that different arrangements of them produce a different meaning of our sentences. Maybe it should be $\exists S \forall x$? I don't know, that's my intuition. Please, do tell me in your answer.

So, have I correctly grasped what parameters are and what they are used for?

Comment: See the answer to your [previous post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3815239/what-are-parameters-in-a-formula-of-first-order-logic)

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I've studied parameters solely in the context of set theory, so I didn't fully understand that previous answer. That's why I asked this further question which is in the context of set theory, so that I might finally understand.

Comment: You can see Thomas Jech, [Set Theory (Springer, 2006)](https://books.google.it/books?id=CZb-CAAAQBAJ&pg=PA5), page 4-5: *parameters* are variables (there are no other choices). And see page 7: *Separation schema* Let $ϕ(u, p)$ be a formula. For any $X$ and $p$, there exists a set $Y$ ...

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thank you.

Comment: A little bit different is the use of "parameters" in the metalanguage; see [Jech, page 157](https://books.google.it/books?id=CZb-CAAAQBAJ&pg=PA157): in this case we have a meta-language expression $\mathfrak A \vDash ϕ[x, a_1,\ldots , a_n]$ where $a_i$ is an element of a set $A$.